# Разница между Trace.IsThreadeSafe и Trace.UseGlobalLock?

Tags: c#

Поясните, как работает эта штука. Мне нужно использовать трассировку для логгирования нескольких потоков в текстовый файл. Нужно ли мне включать свойство IsThreadSafe и почему? И какая разница что использовать - IsThreadSafe true или UseGlobalLock true?

Comment: Выдержка из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.usegloballock(v=vs.110).aspx): _The global lock is always used if the trace listener is not thread safe, regardless of the value of UseGlobalLock. The IsThreadSafe property is used to determine if the listener is thread safe. The global lock is not used only if the value of UseGlobalLock is false and the value of IsThreadSafe is true_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsThreadSafe` - это не свойство класса Trace, это свойство конкретного TraceListner, покаывающего, является ли он потокобезопасным.

При записи в трейс система проверяет `TraceListner.IsThreadSafe`, и если обнаруживает что listner не потокобезопасен (`false`) - добавляет принудительные глобальную блокировку, чтобы не поломать этот listner одновременной записью.

`Trace.UseGlobalLock` включает глобальную блокировку принудительно, вне зависимости от того, что вернул `TraceListener.IsThreadSafe`.

Если вы просто пиште в трейс (используете готовый listener) - то вам ничего включать и менять не нужно. Единственное, что стоит проверить - что у используемого listener `IsThreadSafe` возвращает `true` - иначе, при активной записи в трейс, глобальная блокировка станет бутылочным горлышком в вашем приложении.

Если вы реализуете свой TraceListener - то вы должны переопределить `IsThreadSafe` и вернуть из него реальное значение, соответствующее механизму записи - поддерживает ли ваш listener одновременную запись или нет.

Comment: Допустим, два потока хотят записать свое значение в трейс. Как будет различаться это действие по скорости при IsThreadSafe=true и UseGlobalLock=true?

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов на одиночной записи - почти никак. на 4 потоках которые только пишут в трейс каждый по 1М записей - разница примерно 1300ms на моей машине.